Low resolution on ubuntu
I'm on latitude e7250
Resolution is 1920 x 1080 in display settings.
While I was using windows everything looked perect and things were crisp and clear.
Now I'm on ubuntu, the native ubuntu is same as windows but the other apps like vs code and chrome are pixalated and blurry, the display resolution look to be low than it is actual.
Can it be fixed or ubuntu work like this ?
intel-microcode is installed

Are VS Code and Chrome installed as snap apps or as .deb?

they are installed as snap apps

What version of ubuntu are you running?
It seems that your problem has been raised in a previous thread.
No driver for Intel integrated graphics, Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS
Hope this was helpful for you.

To ask for clarification from the OP, use comments. What has installing Timeshift to do with the OP's question?
